# Where is the input method configuration file?

Tags: linux, xinput, input-method

My `ibus` input method was broken after an update. So I switched to `fcitx`.

Actually, there are a handful IMs (Input Methods) installed in my Fedora 19 system, e.g. fcitx, ibus, yong, etc.

However, I don't know how to configure them. My default IM for `gnome-terminal` is `yong`, `ibus` for `gmrun`. As for `firefox` or `chrome`, I guess they use `ibus` by default, because `GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus`.

There are just-work solutions. I can switch IM by right-click-menu in some applications like `gnome-terminal` or `gmrun`. I can also specify IM with `GTK_IM_MODULE`. But how to do it automatically?

I know the IM settings have something to do with configuration files like

- `~/.xinputrc`
- `/etc/X11/xinit/xinputrc`
- `/etc/X11/xinit/xinput.d/ibus.conf`
- `/etc/X11/xinit/xinput.d/fcitx.conf`
- `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc`
- `/etc/alternatives/xinputrc`

The questions are

- How to configure IM properly?
- What configuration files really matter? In which execution order?

Comment: Do you mean selecting an IME to use by an application or configuring a particular IME?

Comment: You should manage IM with environment variables as suggested by shigazaru. [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/262220/121185) should help you.

Answer (score 1):

I have my X input method selected via env vars

```
$ set | grep fci
GTK_IM_MODULE=fcitx
IM_CONFIG_PREFERRED_RULE=zh_CN,fcitx:zh_TW,fcitx:zh_HK,fcitx:zh_SG,fcitx:ja_JP,fcitx:ko_KR,fcitx:vi_VN,fcitx
QT_IM_MODULE=fcitx
XIM=fcitx
XIM_PROGRAM=fcitx
XMODIFIERS=@im=fcitx
```

And although I use KDE Plasma desktop I have `fcitx-config-gtk3` installed to configure my desired languages and other options

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use the fcitx-configtool to open the fcitx config window and then you can change Extra key for trigger input method to whatever you want.

Then you can cd into the fcitx config folder: cd ~/.config/fcitx and use chmod 444 profile to change the permission of the profile to read only, so that no one can change back to default value.