# Understanding & setting up different input methods

Tags: gnome, input-method, trisquel

I use [Trisquel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trisquel) GNU/Linux 7.0 LTS with GNOME 3 [Flashback](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeFlashback) Environment.

I heard about three different input methods viz. `ibus`, `xim` and `uim`. And it seems `ibus` is pre-installed on my system.

```
$ cat trisquel_7.0_i686.iso.manifest | grep ibus
gir1.2-ibus-1.0 1.5.5-1ubuntu3
ibus 1.5.5-1ubuntu3
ibus-gtk:i386 1.5.5-1ubuntu3
ibus-m17n 1.3.4-3ubuntu1
ibus-table 1.5.0.is.1.5.0.20130419-2
libibus-1.0-5:i386 1.5.5-1ubuntu3
libusb-0.1-4:i386 2:0.1.12-23.3ubuntu1
libusb-1.0-0:i386 2:1.0.17-1ubuntu2
libusbmuxd2 1.0.8-2ubuntu1
libustr-1.0-1:i386 1.0.4-3ubuntu2
```

While facing [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/207025/66803) problem I learnt about installing `uim` and setting up with `GTK_IM_MODULE="uim"` at `~/.profile`. Recently I removed `uim` and removed `GTK_IM_MODULE="uim"` line from `~/.profile`. But to overcome [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit/+bug/367372) bug, I am planning to get rid of `ibus` now.

Without installing any extra input-method, (say fresh-install of Trisquel), `echo $GTK_IM_MODULE` outputs `xim` So, I'm confused because considering default input-method is `ibus`, then **why is `$GTK_IM_MODULE` saying `xim`?**

**Also can I `apt-get remove ibus`? or I should install `uim` first and then remove `ibus`? Also I want to know which input method is currently working `ibus` or `xim`? And What is the right way to set the input method (i.e is it `GTK_IM_MODULE="uim"` to `~/.profile`)?**

Besides,I found one gsettings scheme:

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-im-module
'gtk-im-context-simple'
```

Briefly/Broadly I need help to understand installing/removing and setting-up different input method:

- How do I know which input-method is currently active?
- How do I install and set-up different input-method? (should I remove another?)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The whole X11 input stack is a mess. First of all, you don't need any special input method framework if you're just typing latin characters or multi-character compose sequences as defined by your XKB keyboard layout. Strictly speaking, any multi-key sequences, such as dead-keys, require a very simple input method. But they are provided by libx11/XKB and work without any additional IM framework. So it is perfectly fine to uninstall all of ibus, uim, fcitx or whatever input method you have if you don't need to type languages such as Chinese or Japanese.

As you already said, Gnome made ibus the default input method, a decision not everybody was happy about back then. There are many people who prefer fcitx (which seems to be the default for most KDE distributions) over ibus. Further, there were apparently several missing features in ibus that fcitx had, at least when this now very dated [LWN article](https://lwn.net/Articles/503320/) was published in 2012, such as incomplete language support (mostly Japanese vs. simplified vs. traditional Chinese) or performance issues. Since I don't speak any eastern languages which need a special IM framework, I can't really add anything to that debate and it's likely that most of these issues have been fixed. I mostly notice that ibus doesn't integrate well with non-GTK desktop environments from a user interface standpoint, but for GTK-based DEs it's probably fine.

However, the fact that ibus is the default IM for Gnome doesn't make it obligatory. You can use any other input method you like or none at all. The IM configuration is done via environment variables. But except for when you're solely using GTK+ applications (which I doubt), you should set more than just `GTK_IM_MODULE`. The proper way of setting an input method is:

```
export GTK_IM_MODULE="fcitx"
export QT_IM_MODULE="fcitx"
export XMODIFIERS="@im=fcitx"
```

in case of fcitx or

```
export GTK_IM_MODULE="ibus"
export QT_IM_MODULE="ibus"
export XMODIFIERS="@im=ibus"
```

in case of ibus. uim works in the same way. If you want to explicitly disable any input method, use these settings:

```
export GTK_IM_MODULE="gtk-im-context-simple"
export QT_IM_MODULE="simple"
```

An empty string works as well.

You can set these variables either system-wide in `/etc/profile` (or a dedicated file inside `/etc/profile.d`, respectively) or inside your local `~/.xprofile`. Setting it in `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` will not ensure that the lines will be executed when logging into your system using a graphical login manager such as GDM, SDDM, KDM or LightDM. If you are starting your X session using XDM, Slim or `startx`, you need to put those lines in `~/.xinitrc`.

If you configured an input method other than ibus, go to Gnome settings afterwards and make sure any ibus-related settings are disabled, especially any keyboard shortcuts. Alternatively, tell Gnome not to touch your keyboard settings using:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.keyboard active false
```

or uninstall ibus altogether.

Now what about XIM? XIM is a pretty obsolete input method protocol which both ibus and fcitx implement for legacy support reasons only. There is no real reason why you would want to use XIM nowadays over any of those two. The only reason why you would want to set `GTK_IM_MODULE="xim"` is to [override GTK's hardcoded ComposeKey settings](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey#XIM).

To answer your other question: I don't think there is really a way of detecting which input method is active at the moment except for looking at the environment variables or knowing which IMs are installed on your system. If `GTK_IM_MODULE` is not set, GTK selects a built-in IM on the basis of configurations in `/etc/gtk-2.0/gtk.immodules`. GTK 3.0 looks in `/usr/lib/gtk-3.0/3.0.0/immodules.cache` which is generated by `gtk-query-immodules-3.0`.

The reason why `GTK_IM_MODULE` is set to `xim` is probably some stray variable definition somewhere in `/etc/profile`, `/etc/profile.d/*` or any other of your local or global shell RC files. Feel free to unset or override this variable if you feel the need to do so.

However, according to this [Gnome bug report comment](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=747825#c6) I assume that the value configured via `gsettings` overrides the value set in `GTK_IM_MODULE` for DBus-activated applications. So at least your Gnome applications are probably using `gtk-im-context-simple` at the moment which effectively means standard behavior (i.e. no ibus or any other dedicated IM).

Comment: Great explanation and background. Now if only `gsettings` didn't segfault on me whenever I try to do anything xD (even --version segfaults!!)

Comment: So I have ibus and xim on my Ubuntu 18.04. Can I safely delete them both if I have no intention to type in CJK languages?

Comment: Yes, but I wouldn't uninstall XIM unless needed. It's very dated, but sometimes used as base for other functionality. So unless you really need the few kB, I wouldn't uninstall it.